# Let's get critical: Dec 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Freelancing Stack Exchange](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: So far, the questions I've reviewed appear very high in the search results, even using the incognito mode of the browser. Not sure if that's a fluke or not. I also edited some of the posts to improve them, and am hoping  [someone more knowledgeable than me can make this be more than a link-only answer](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8874/freelancing).

Comment: Looks like the answerer edited the link only post. So that looks a lot better now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What's the smallest unit of time I should charge for when clients request minor changes?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/926/whats-the-smallest-unit-of-time-i-should-charge-for-when-clients-request-minor)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [At what stage in negotiations do you ask for the budget? If at all?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/883/at-what-stage-in-negotiations-do-you-ask-for-the-budget-if-at-all)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [A dress code during a freelance interview?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/892/a-dress-code-during-a-freelance-interview)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Client wants to pay a percentage of revenue generated by website](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/917/client-wants-to-pay-a-percentage-for-revenue-generated-by-website)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Should I charge my client the same rate for support services as I do for development, especially if I subcontract the support work?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/855/should-i-charge-my-client-the-same-rate-for-support-services-as-i-do-for-develop)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How Do I Start my Own Freelancing Company?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/871/how-do-i-start-my-own-freelancing-company)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What taxes does a Canadian freelancer charge to other countries?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/874/what-taxes-does-a-canadian-freelancer-charge-to-other-countries)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Health insurance and freelancing in the US](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/888/health-insurance-and-freelancing-in-the-us)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Clients who don't pay their invoices what are your options?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/842/clients-who-dont-pay-their-invoices-what-are-your-options)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Are there measures one can do to ensure clients paying on time?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/843/are-there-measures-one-can-do-to-ensure-clients-paying-on-time)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)

---